# Xamarin : How To Fire Event From PCL In android , how to call addReminder From PCL

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.android

Xamarin Project
PCL
Android
IOS

I have a method in Android.MainActivity 
and want to call  it from PCL

Comment: please send the full question with exception

Comment: use DependencyService: https://developer.xamarin.com/guides/xamarin-forms/application-fundamentals/dependency-service/

Answer (score 3):

The default architecture of solution will always be UI->PCL. UI project will have reference to PCL project. So, code in UI project (MainActivity) can call/reference to class/method in PCL. But PCL is not able to call/reference back to class/method in UI project. This is also to avoid cyclic reference.

In order to what you plan to do, you have 2 options:

**Option 1**

Use Dependency service. You can refer to guide in [HERE](https://developer.xamarin.com/guides/xamarin-forms/application-fundamentals/dependency-service/) to learn more about it. Basically it register the UI type to an interface and PCL call through the interface.

**Option 2**

PCL class have an event

```
public event Action SomeEvent;
```

MainActivity will register the event and call to the method that you want to call.

```
[PCL class].SomeEvent += SomeEventHandlerMethod;
```

Then whenever you want to call to MainActivity method in PCL, just invoke the event.

```
SomeEvent();
```

Comment: Option 2 worked for me

Answer (score 0):

please send the full question with exception. use [MessagingCenter](https://developer.xamarin.com/guides/xamarin-forms/application-fundamentals/messaging-center/) may be this one solved your requirement.

Comment: sorry ... although i had to add Code StackOverFlow neglect it